# Как загрузить видео с момента, где в последний раз был ползунок, используя localstorage? Не используя video.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь реализовать фишку сайта YouTube, а именно следующее: хочу сохранять момент, где в последний раз была совершена остановка (т.е не пауза, а где находился ползунок), с помощью localstorage, чтобы при обновлении страницы видео начиналось с этого момента.

Мой код:

```
   window.onload = function()
   {
       var currentTime = video.currentTime = localStorage.test; 
       //ТУТ БЫЛО '18' ДО ТОГО, КАК Я ЗАМЕНИЛ ЕГО НА 'localStorage.test' 
       //THERE WAS '18' BEFORE I REPLACED IT WITH 'localStorage.test'           
       localStorage.test = currentTime;
       console.log(localStorage.test);

    }
```

Однако, получается сохранить только конкретно заданное значение **currentTime** в localstorage, например, начав видео с 18 секунды, но как это сделать для момента, где произошла последняя остановка на видео?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Нужно убрать `var currentTime` и использовать `video.currentTime` для получения актуальной информации о текущем времени проигрывания видео.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myVideo");

x.ontimeupdate = function () {
    localStorage.setItem('time', this.currentTime);
};

window.onload = function(){
    let time = localStorage.getItem('time');
    if (time){
        setCurTime(time);
    }
};

function setCurTime(time) { 
    x.currentTime = time;
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video><br>
```